# How to set the JavaScript else value to the original value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, coldfusion-2016

I've am using the JQuery data table pulling the data from the database. My question is I have a conditional statement the check for a value in the database and if it is 1 set the text to "FINISHED" else show the value in another column in the database like shown in the example below.

{

```
                     "render": function ( data, type, row )
                     {
                      var appstat = 'black';
                       if (row[5] == 1) {
                        appstat = 'green';
                        TextStatus = 'FINISHED';
                        IconChoice = 'fa fa-check';
                      } 
                       else  {
                        appstat = 'black';
                        var TextStatus = "row[7]";
                        IconChoice = 'fa fa-angle-double-right';
                      }
                      return '<span style="color:' + appstat + '">' + TextStatus + ' <i class="' + IconChoice + '"></i></span>';
                    },
                    "targets": -3
            },
```

When I run this, it shows the FINISHED or row[7] not the value of row 7. Does anyone know why?

Comment: because ```"row[7]"``` is declared as a literal string, you may want to write it like so: ```var TextStatus = row[7];```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes:

```
var TextStatus = row[7];
```

Or use string interpolation:

```
var TextStatus = `${row[7]}`
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. I am still a bit rusty with JS. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double quotes from row[7]

```
var TextStatus = "row[7]";
//Change to 
var TextStatus = row[7];
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `else` clause you're setting the value of the variable to a string. Please get rid of the double quotes and you should have access to the variable itself.

Instead of

```
TextStatus = "row[7]"
```

put

```
TextStatus = row[7]
```

Comment: Roger that, thank you. This worked great. Thank god for stack overflow and everyone that contributes.

Answer (score 0):

Like discribed in the post above

I modified the code to read `TextStatus = row[7]`

Works perfectly.